# /flutter ( 7217): Response Data: {statusCode: 500, Message:

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Everything is working fine on post but when I try to post data through flutter application then I get this message show:

[image]

On console jsonencode showing correct data:

```
Class _CheckoutScreenState extends State<CheckoutScreen> {
  final TextEditingController addressController = TextEditingController();
  bool isAddressValid = false; // Track the validity of the address
  Future<void> placeOrder(List<Map<String, dynamic>> data,
      String customerAddress, String customerNote) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = await prefs.getString(
        'action'); // Replace 'action' with your token key from shared preferences
    String baseurl = BaseUrl().baseUrl;
    String apiUrl = '$baseurl/api/customer/order/create';

    try {
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(apiUrl),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          "products": data,
          "customer_address": customerAddress,
          "customer_note": customerNote,
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // If the server returns a 200 OK response, parse the response data
        var responseData = json.decode(response.body);
        // Print the data before sending
        print('Response Data: $responseData');
        // Clear the cart items from SharedPreferences
        prefs.remove('cart_items');
      } else {
        // If the server did not return a 200 OK response, handle the error
        print('Failed to post data: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle other exceptions if any
      print('Error: $error');
    }
  }
```